# Int and string together

Tags: c#

Its my code :

```
 if (numavg <=3 ){
             Console.WriteLine("Congratz, we can start! but some note before :");
             Console.WriteLine("When you put the last number, type 'c' in the next line for calculate the avg");
             Console.WriteLine("So lets start! type the first number.");
             avg1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             Console.WriteLine("Ok, so you choose " + avg1 + ",who is the next number?");
             avg2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             Console.WriteLine("Wonderful! put the next number");
             avg3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             if (avg3 = "c"){
                 Console.WriteLine("Ok, Lets calculate!");
                 average = (avg1 + avg2)/numavg;
                 Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average + ".");


             }
             else {
                 Console.WriteLine("Perfect! please type the next number,or 'c' for avg to the last 3 numbers.");
                 avg4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                 if (avg4 = "c" ){
                     Console.WriteLine("Ok, Lets calculate!");
                     average1 = (avg1 + avg2 + avg3)/numavg;
                     Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average1 + ".");



             }

         }
```

The problem is with type "c" (for calculate the avg).
I dont understand how I can keep avg3 and avg4 as string and int together.

help?

and more pure question - 
If I want the program end and restart automaticlly, which code I need type?
(if the restart isn't possible, how can I do the first thing with the auto program closing?)

Thank u guys!

NOTE :
The error is "  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'".

Comment: If you need to store two different types then use two different variable.

Comment: do you mean `if (avg3 == "c")` instead of  `if (avg3 = "c")`

Comment: Please take a look on the code, how can I do it? Its need be something who can make average of maximum 3 numbers.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I tried it... its not help.

Comment: `=` means you are assigning it, `==` means you are comparing it

Comment: Ok, but what I need to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do you mean `if(avg3 == "c")` instead of  `if (avg3 = "c")`

`(avg3 = "c")` you are assigning `"c"` to `avg3` which is of type `int` which explains `" Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'".`

```
String avg3Str = Console.ReadLine();
if (avg3Str.equals("c")){
 Console.WriteLine("Ok, Lets calculate!");
 average = (avg1 + avg2)/numavg;
 Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average + ".");
}
else {
 avg3 = int.Parse(avg3Str);
 Console.WriteLine("Perfect! please type the next number,or 'c' for avg to the last 3 numbers.");
 String avg4Str = Console.ReadLine();
 if (avg4Str.equals("c") ){
     Console.WriteLine("Ok, Lets calculate!");
     average1 = (avg1 + avg2 + avg3)/numavg;
     Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average1 + ".");
 }
 else
 {
  avg4 = int.Parse(avg4Str);
  Console.WriteLine("Ok, Lets calculate!");
     average1 = (avg1 + avg2 + avg3 + avg4)/numavg;
     Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average1 + ".");
 }

}
```

Comment: @Omer: did you solve the problem?